# Trying to understand the concept of resistance

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance

I am a software developer trying to teach myself some basic concepts of how electromagnetism works. At high school we were taught about electricity in all kinds of metaphors that, I realize now, really do not fit the model at all.

What I understand so far (correct me if I am wrong)

- Electric energy in simple terms is the kinetic energy held by electrons, usually transferred to them by placing them in a electric field.
- Because of this, electrons are manipulated to travel (drift) through conductors by introducing a charge (let's say a negative one) at one end of the conductor, and a charge with a relatively less negative charge at the other end, recursively creating a continuous series of electric fields throughout the conductor.

Now something that I can't find anywhere on the internet (I'm sure I haven't looked hard enough) is how these electrons convert their kinetic energy into other forms of energy, or, how resistance *actually* stops electrons from speeding up "forever" until they reach the end of the field.

My intuition tells me these electrons must slam into atoms or other particles that hang around within the conductor, transferring their kinetic energy (thus slowing them down) to whatever they collide with. I've assumed through my reading that electrons colliding with atoms (causing them to move) is what is causing a conductor to warm up.

Are these assumptions in some ways correct?
This is currently my way to explain how a (Edison) light bulb actually radiates light: drifting electrons heat up a specific part of the circuit (I guess it would be material with a very high resistance) by colliding "a lot" with the particles inside that part of the circuit. Why a material starts emitting photon's at a certain temperature isn't part of my explanation but I think it's not very relevant to what I am currently trying to understand.

Then: how does the concept of resistance work in a circuit containing something like an electric engine? I think I know electric engines work by current running through different coils creating magnetic fields, which cause other parts to move (because magnets, I will dive into magnetism later). Since energy cannot just "appear", the kinetic energy in the engine *must* be transferred from the moving electrons that create the magnetic field. How does this transformation work? And would this transfer of energy  also count towards the resistance of the engine within the circuit?

I hope I've been able to give context about what I am trying to grasp... Apologies for misusing (or not at all) using correct terminology.

Answer (score 1):

> Electric energy in simple terms is the kinetic energy held by electrons, usually transferred to them by placing them in a electric field.

Electric energy has almost nothing to do with the KE of electrons in an ordinary circuit. Electric energy is about the fields, not the electrons. The energy is transported through the fields outside and immediately adjacent to the wire, per [Poynting's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting%27s_theorem).

> My intuition tells me these electrons must slam into atoms or other particles that hang around within the conductor, transferring their kinetic energy (thus slowing them down) to whatever they collide with.

This is known as the Drude model. It is quite crude and has many failings, but it is a reasonable "first-order approximation" type of explanation. However, this is energy dissipation rather than energy transport. The energy for this comes from the fields outside the wire where a portion of the energy flux is directed inwards towards the wire instead of parallel to the wire.

> Since energy cannot just "appear", the kinetic energy in the engine must be transferred from the moving electrons that create the magnetic field. How does this transformation work?

This does not happen. The energy comes to the motor in the electromagnetic fields from the wire which directly feed the varying magnetic fields in the motor. There is no need for KE in the electrons to be changed. A hypothetical motor made with no-resistance windings would work just fine.

Comment: When you say "Electric energy is about the fields, not the electrons" I must ask, what form of energy is then caused by the fields? From what I understand, the fields present cuase electrons or particles with a charge to move. Creating the field would require energy to amass charge that would create the potential of the field.

Comment: Also, "There is no need for KE in the electrons to be changed", isn't it so that magnetic fields are only present when charged particles move? If there was no moving (KE) electrons, there would be no current in the coils and thus no magnetic fields right?

Comment: @Glubus the EM field itself is a form of energy with the energy density being $0.5(\epsilon_0 E^2 + B^2/\mu_0)$. I have added a link to Poynting's theorem that describes energy transfer in EM. If you have questions about energy transfer in EM then that is the place to start. Yes, electrons move but the KE of the moving electrons is irrelevant and there is no need for the KE to go in or out of the electrons in order to transfer energy. Similarly, a bike chain moves, but the KE of the bike chain is not what drives the bike and its KE does not need to change to transfer energy

Comment: Thanks Dale, I will read what you've linked me!

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the last part, with the magnet in the motor.

When you will learn about magnets, you will see that moving magnets create electric fields, meaning that when a current creates a magnetic field which accelerates a magnet, it can be shown that the magnet creates an electric field that opposes the current, meaning the current loses energy when the magnet gains energy due to magnetic forces.